# Creating an Python np vstack of different sized hstacks

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm converting the following MATLAB code into Python:

```
function segments = segmentSlidingWindow(data, wSize, sSize)
    len = size(data,1);
    wCurr = 1;
    segments = []; % todo: init to make faster
    while (wCurr<len-wSize)
        segments = [segments; wCurr wCurr+wSize]; % start stop
        wCurr = wCurr+sSize; % step forward
    end
    segments = [segments; wCurr len]; % add residual
end
```

I wrote the following Python code following the [Numpy for Matlab users guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

```
def sliding_window(data, window_size, step_size):
    length = data.shape[0]
    wCurr = 0
    segments = []
    while wCurr < length - window_size:
        segments = np.vstack([np.hstack([segments]), np.hstack([wCurr, window_size + wCurr])])
        wCurr = wCurr + step_size
    segments = np.vstack([np.hstack([segments]), np.hstack([wCurr, length])])
    plt.plot(segments)
    plt.show()
    return segments
```

I'm also plotting the segmented data to see what it looks like. However, I can't run this Python code because on the line:

```
segments = np.vstack([np.hstack([segments]), np.hstack([wCurr, window_size + wCurr])])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

When I print `length` I get `504`

My data is a pandas DataFrame with 5 columns. I only want a sliding window on the middle three columns as they are the only ones that are relevant. The first column is a time stamp and the last one is a label.

`wSize` and `sSize` are integers.

I want to make a sliding window for something like this:

```
 1495573445.162, 0, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1
 1495573445.172, 0, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1
 1495573445.182, 0, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1
 1495573445.192, 0, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1
 1495573445.202, 0, 0.021194, 0.012161, -0.994705, 1
 1495573445.212, 0, 0.019638, 0.013718, -0.994019, 1
 1495573445.222, 0, 0.019440, 0.010803, -0.994476, 1
 1495573445.232, 0, 0.018112, 0.010849, -0.993073, 1
 1495573445.242, 0, 0.020157, 0.011154, -0.994644, 1
 1495573445.252, 0, 0.020340, 0.010040, -0.995804, 1
 1495573445.262, 0, 0.017792, 0.009857, -0.996078, 1
 1495573445.272, 0, 0.020538, 0.010239, -0.994858, 1
```

where the output would be a rolling window with a step size half the window size.

Comment: Could you, please, provide some test data (really small numpy arrays?

Comment: Your code works for me with the following simulated data: `segments = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])`, `wCurr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`, and `window_size = np.array([[10,20],[30,40]])`. Then `segments = np.vstack([np.hstack([segments]), np.hstack([wCurr, window_size + wCurr])])` works and the new value of `segments` is: `array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4], [ 5,  6,  7,  8], [ 1,  2, 11, 22], [ 3,  4, 33, 44]])`

Comment: You really need to provide your example data or at least shapes of each of the input arrays. In fact shapes would suffice.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: do the following before your `segments = ...` statement: Add print(segments.shape); print(wCurr.shape); print(window_size.shape)` NOTE: last print makes sense if `window_size` is an array and not an integer number. Running `len(array)` returns total length of the array and not its shape.

Comment: `wCurr` and `window_size` are integers

Comment: Then I am failing to understand what are you trying to do. Posting some test data and *expected output* would greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that most likely you would like to replace your `while` loop with something like this:

```
s = np.arange(0, length - window_size, step_size)
segments = np.vstack([s, s + window_size]).T
```

For `length = 15; step_size = 3; window_size = 6;` segments will look like:

```
array([[ 0, 6],
       [ 3, 9],
       [ 6, 12]])
```

If you would like the transposed answer, remove`.T` after `vstack` in the above code, obtaining:

```
array([[ 0,  3,  6],
       [ 6,  9, 12]])
```

If you really insist on using the `while` loop, then:

```
segments = np.empty((0, 2), dtype=np.int)
while wCurr < length - window_size:
    segments = np.vstack([segments, [wCurr, window_size + wCurr]])
    wCurr = wCurr + step_size
```

or:

```
segments = np.empty((0, 2), dtype=np.int)
while wCurr < length - window_size:
    segments = np.append(segments, [[wCurr, window_size + wCurr]], axis=0)
    wCurr = wCurr + step_size
```